# How to find a contact location in a B/W image?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, ocr, emgucv

I am working on a very specific OCR using OpenCV to analyse a B/W image. I need to be able to distinct contours of elements which are touching each other.

I am searching for the best (fastest) way to "split" a single contour object in two new contours sliced at the thinner contact point.
The big part is finding this thinner point.

For example:

When using Times New Roman, the characters in the word `tu` are touching each other (the horizontal line of `t` is linked to the top of the `u`). I need to find the X value of the point between `t` and `u` in order to get two contours (from the X value I can "easily" get a bounding-box as ROI on each elements and get a contour from there).

I think this seems similar to finding a bottleneck shape on a tube image.
Anyone have an ideas? I already tried eroding the image, but that causes issues with the `r` characters.

Comment: you also can see that, it's too tedious to read out this article!

Comment: While posting your question be specific,so that others can easily help you out.

Comment: @GrawCube thanks for your edit.  It makes reading this post so much easier.